# Catch exception, then throw/send exception and continue

Tags: c#, winforms, exception, try-catch

So the title might be bit misleading, but what I wanted to accomplish is reading an array of files and then combine them into one, which is where I am now.

The problem is that I have a catch that looks for the exception "FileNotFoundException", when this is called I want to continue my try statement (Using "continue") but let the user know that the file is missing.

My setup is a class that is called from a form (It's in the form where the error should show up)

I thought about creating an event that can be registered from my form, but is that the right way?

```
    public void MergeClientFiles(string directory)
    {
        // Find all clients
        Array clients = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Clients));

        // Create a new array of files
        string[] files = new string[clients.Length];

        // Combine the clients with the .txt extension
        for (int i = 0; i < clients.Length; i++)
            files[i] = clients.GetValue(i) + ".txt";

        // Merge the files into directory
        using (var output = File.Create(directory))
        {
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                try
                {
                    using (var input = File.OpenRead(file))
                    {
                        input.CopyTo(output);
                    }
                }
                catch (FileNotFoundException)
                {
                    // Its here I want to send the error to the form
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the method to do its job and report user about problems, right?
Then Oded has suggested right thing. With small modification, the code could look like this:

```
    public List<string> MergeClientFiles( string path )
    {
        // Find all clients
        Array clients = Enum.GetValues( typeof( Clients ) );

        // Create a new array of files
        string[] files = new string[clients.Length];

        // Combine the clients with the .txt extension
        for( int i = 0; i < clients.Length; i++ )
            files[i] = clients.GetValue( i ) + ".txt";
        List<string> errors = new List<string>();

        // Merge the files into AllClientData
        using( var output = File.Create( path ) ) {
            foreach( var file in files ) {
                try {
                    using( var input = File.OpenRead( file ) ) {
                        input.CopyTo( output );
                    }
                }
                catch( FileNotFoundException ) {
                    errors.Add( file );
                }
            }
        }
        return errors;
    }
```

Then, in caller you just check if MergeClientFiles returns non-empty collection.

Comment: I think I will go with this answer. It makes sense for the method to take care of returning the errors and for the form to figure out if there are any errors to report.

Answer (score 2):

You can collect the exceptions into a `List<FileNotFoundException>` and at the end of iteration, if the list is **not** empty, throw a custom exception assigning this list to a corresponding member.

This will allow any code calling the above to catch your custom exception, iterate over the `FileNotFoundException`s and notify the user.

Answer (score 1):

you could define a delegate that you pass as an argument of your method.

```
public delegate void FileNotFoundCallback(string file);

public void MergeClientFiles(string directory, FileNotFoundCallback callback)
{
    // Find all clients
    Array clients = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Clients));

    // Create a new array of files
    string[] files = new string[clients.Length];

    // Combine the clients with the .txt extension
    for (int i = 0; i < clients.Length; i++)
        files[i] = clients.GetValue(i) + ".txt";

    // Merge the files into directory
    using (var output = File.Create(directory))
    {
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var input = File.OpenRead(file))
                {
                    input.CopyTo(output);
                }
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException)
            {
                // Its here I want to send the error to the form
                callback( file );
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For some inspiration, have a look at the documentation for the new parallel constructs in c#, such as Parallel.For and the [Reactive Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609.aspx) (rx).

In the first, exceptions are collected in an [AggregateException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.aggregateexception.aspx), in Rx exceptions are communicated via a callback interface.

I think I prefer the approach used in Parallel.For, but choose what fits your scenario best.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than catching `FileNotFoundException`s you should actively check if the file exists and then don't try to open it if it doesn't.

You can change the method to return a list of merged files, a list of missing files, or a list of all files along with an indicator if they were merged or missing.  Returning a single list gives the caller the option to process the missing files all at once and know how many were missing, instead of one-by-one as would be the case with an event or callback.